# Is it enough to show that function is a valid kernel if it is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, machine-learning, positive-semidefinite

I've been studying kernel methods in my course and in a textbook came across an additional line (aside from the positive definiteness of the Gram/Kernel Matrix).

That it should be enough for a kernel to be a valid inner product.

Now for one of last years exercises I found that $\frac{1}{K(x,y)}$ for a valid Kernel $K(x,y)$ is not a valid kernel.
The proof is given by showing that the matrix is not necessarily positive definite (which is easy to follow).
That however confuses me, because if the rule stated above holds, then $K(x,y)$ is an inner product.
I can show that the reciprocal is also symmetric and linear with a little algebra. Positive semi-definitenes seems to also be guaranteed.
And thus I arrive at contradictory statements.
Do I overlook something major (probably)?

I am suspecting I am doing something wrong with my attempt at showing the reciprocal is an inner product.

thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "positive semi-definiteness seems to also be guaranteed"? The example given in the proof you mention seems to show that it this is not necessarily the case

Comment: Also, note that it is not usually correct to say that a kernel $K(x,y)$ "is an inner product" even if that kernel is valid.

Comment: hi @BenGrossmann I meant that the inner product $\frac{1}{K(x,x)}$ is always > 0 because $K(x,x)$ is > 0.
Thanks! I think your second comment made me understand, so all kernels have to be inner products, but an inner product is not necessarily a kernel?

Comment: It's the opposite: inner products are kernels, but kernels are not necessarily inner products. The point of the [M-A theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore%E2%80%93Aronszajn_theorem) is that a kernel *corresponds to* an inner product (over a reproducing kernel Hilbert space), but the kernel is not technically (necessarily) an inner product.

Comment: Note that the condition that $K(x,x) > 0$ for all $x$ is not enough to make $K$ a valid kernel. If (a symmetric function) $K$ satisfies $K(x,x) > 0$ **and** is linear in each argument, then $K$ must be a kernel because it is an inner product.

Comment: I see, that's how I originally understood it @BenGrossmann.

But then, if $K(x, y)$ is a valid kernel, how can $\frac{1}{K(x,y)}$ not be a valid kernel?
Because the reciprocal should also be linear and I can not see how it could be $<0$

Comment: If $1/K(x,y)$ is **not** linear in each argument (which is usually true), then the fact that $1/K(x,x)  > 0$ for all non-zero $x$ is **not** enough to ensure that $1/K(x,y)$ is a kernel.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you! 
I made a huge blunder, I think I can see now how it's not linear, I was pulling $\frac{1}{scalar}$ out of the fraction but made an algebraic mistake by using it as $scalar$ thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments: the main misconception seems to have been that if $K(x,y)$ is linear in each of its arguments, then $1/K(x,y)$ must also be linear in each of its arguments. However, this is not the case. Thus, the condition that $1/K(x,x) > 0$ for all $x$ is not sufficient to ensure that $1/K(x,y)$ defines an inner product.

Comment: This is correct, thank you Ben for your patience and insight!